# Xbox360 / XNA homebrewing

Tags: xna, xbox360

It's possible to deploy XNA games to Xbox360 without AppHub/XNA Creators subscription ? It cost 99$ which isn't expensive, but I don't want (at this time) sell my game at marketplace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this you must have a membership:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/21375.aspx

> Re: Deploying XNA Games Reply Quote
> Yes, you must deploy from your PC - you can deploy from within Visual Studio or by deploying a .ccgame  file using the XnaPack utility.
>
> Yes, you must have a Creators Club membership and download the XNA Game Studio Connect software to be able > to deploy games to your Xbox 360.
>
> Thanks!
> Aaron Stebner, XNA Development Platform team, Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Ok, I'll invest to XNA creators subscription soon, thanks for info!